# javascript find same position in rotated element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a "base" reference rect (red)

Inside a rotated div (#map), I need a clone rect (yellow), it has to be same size and position of "base" rect, independent of its parent (#map) rotation.

This is where I am so far, any help would be welcoming.

http://codepen.io/christianpugliese/pen/oXKOda

```
var controls = { degrees: 0, rectX:125, rectY:55 };

var wBounds = document.getElementById("wrapper").getBoundingClientRect(),
    mapBounds = document.getElementById("map").getBoundingClientRect(),
    rectBounds = document.getElementById("rect").getBoundingClientRect();

   var _x = ((mapBounds.width - wBounds.width) / 2) +   $('#rect').position().left,
       _y = ((mapBounds.height - wBounds.height) / 2) + $('#rect').position().top;

  $('#rect').css({top: controls.rectY+'px', left:controls.rectX+'px'});

  $('#mapRect').width(rectBounds.width);
  $('#mapRect').height(rectBounds.height);
  $('#mapRect').css({top: _y+'px',
                     left:_x+'px',
                    'transform': 'rotate('+ Math.round(-controls.degrees) +'deg)'});

  $('#map').css('transform', 'rotate('+ Math.round(controls.degrees) +'deg)');
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using absolute positioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're rotating the `#mapRect` an equal amount in the opposite direction you're getting rotation/orientation right but not the origin. The `transform-origin` would be the center of the `#mapBounds`, but relative to the `#rect`;

Fork of your pen: http://codepen.io/MisterCurtis/pen/vNBYZJ?editors=101

Since there is some rounding/subpixel positioning happening the yellow rect doesn't align pixel perfect.

```
function updateUI(){
  var _x = ((mapBounds.width - wBounds.width) / 2) + $('#rect').position().left,
  _y = ((mapBounds.height - wBounds.height) / 2) + $('#rect').position().top,
  _ox = mapBounds.width/2 - _x, // origin x
  _oy = mapBounds.height/2 - _y; // origin y

...

  $('#mapRect').css({
    'transform-origin': _ox + 'px ' + _oy + 'px', // now it rotates by the bounds
    top: _y + 'px',
    left: _x + 'px',
    'transform': 'rotate(' + Math.round(-controls.degrees) + 'deg)'
  });
}
```

Edit: Updated the [pen](http://codepen.io/MisterCurtis/pen/vNBYZJ). You'll have to ditch using Rectangle and instead use Polygon. This way you can use a plugin like https://github.com/ahmadnassri/google-maps-polygon-rotate to perform the rotation along the map center.

Comment: Thanks! It does it for the local div, but does not work for the map projection, I guess because it breaks the positions. I updated the code with the projection.

Comment: @Chris I've updated the pen to rotate the projection. You'll have to use a plugin to perform the rotation on a map Polygon (it is a bit jittery). Some tinkering you could probably address pixel rounding and get it a little more exact since the projection is offset quite a bit.

Comment: sorry to bother @MisterCurtis, but any idea on how I could solve an applied scale to the map div as well? size-wise is ok, but position is broken: http://codepen.io/christianpugliese/pen/oXKOda?editors=001